# How to create an RSS feed in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, rss

I have to create an RSS feed for the ASP.NET website I am developing.

How can I create an RSS feed in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RssToolkit](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/) , its very easy to use. click [here](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Producing%20Feeds&referringTitle=Home) for publishing RSS feed

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class and friends in [`System.ServiceModel.Syndication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx). It also allows outputting a number of formats, like Atom, and lets you attach or parse extended information.